# Start computer and open all windows as before

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office, workflow

I have a setup with 3 monitors. Normally I have word, chrome, acrobat etc open at the same time and everything is in its place. Is there a way to shut down the computer in a way it remembers the whole "session" and restarts everything exactly as it was last time so I don't have to reopen everything again and put every window in its place?

Comment: You could probably create an [autohotkey](https://autohotkey.com/) script that launches all the programs you want and then moves their windows to the relevant screen. https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/32874-moving-the-active-window-from-one-monitor-to-the-other/

Comment: Yes, it's called Sleep and also Hibernate.